# MySQL How to Group While Sorting Query Result?

Tags: mysql, sorting, group-by, sql-order-by, union

So I have a table named 'films' like this for example;

```
 |id|title |rating|
 |1 |Qwerty|4     |
 |2 |Zxcv  |0     |
 |3 |Asdf  |2     |
 |4 |Jkl   |0     |
 |5 |Uiop  |5     |
```

So I Want to query the table and the result must be sorted by title but all data with rating greater than zero showed first, and also could limit the result, so for example from that table, i would like the query result like this;

```
expected result with LIMIT 5
 |id|title |rating|
 |3 |Asdf  |2     |
 |5 |Uiop  |5     |
 |1 |Qwerty|4     |
 |4 |Jkl   |0     |
 |2 |Zxcv  |0     |

expected result with LIMIT 2
 |id|title |rating|
 |3 |Asdf  |2     |
 |5 |Uiop  |5     |
```

I have tried this code,

```
 (SELECT * FROM films WHERE rating > 0 ORDER BY title) 
 UNION ALL 
 (SELECT * FROM films WHERE rating = 0 ORDER BY title) LIMIT 5
```

but the `order by` inside the `()` is neglected, when using `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build something to order by as a statement

You should be able to use something like

```
mysql> select * from films order by concat(if(rating > 0,0, 1), title);
+-------+--------+
| title | rating |
+-------+--------+
| aaa   |      3 |
| ccc   |      5 |
| bbb   |      0 |
+-------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In this case, the 0 or 1 gets prepended to the title name when sorting, you could use 'a' and  'b', or anything that can be used for sorting

Comment: WOW this is actually WORKS. Thanks A Lot!!
Very Nice Logic, using concat and if for workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using order by inside unions.  This would cause two layers of sorting to occur.  For details on why, please read here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

For your example, a query that would find all movies and sort them by title and rating is:

```
SELECT * FROM films ORDER BY rating DESC, title;
```

This query first grabs all films, then orders by rating with greater rating first (specified by `DESC`, then by film title.  In the same order as the query is read.

Comment: I've tried this also but the result is also not like the expected, because it will be sorted by rating first, but the title would appear not in order. so as for my example with your query code the result would be (id) 5,1,3,4,2, while as you can see above i expect the the result to be 3,5,1,4,2, because the title appear in order, while grouping all films with rating on top result.

Comment: Solved with answer From Oliver, Thanks for your reply anyway!

Answer (score 0):

you need to `orderby` after union two query than it will work. if you understand how limit is working here than you should understand how order by is working

```
(SELECT * FROM films WHERE rating > 0 ) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT * FROM films WHERE rating = 0 ORDER BY title) ORDER BY title LIMIT 5
```

Comment: I've tried this also but the result is also not like the expected, because in the end the union result will be ordered by name but do not group all films with rating above zero on top result, so as for my example with your query code the result is going to be (id) 3,4,1,5,2, while as you can see above i expect the the result to be 3,5,1,4,2, because the title appear in order, while grouping all films with rating on top result

Comment: Solved with answer From Oliver, Thanks for your reply anyway!